# Who is Mizuki in SawanoHiroyuki[nZk]:mizuki?

Tags: music, aldnoah-zero, hiroyuki-sawano

I really liked the songs sung by "Mizuki" of SawanoHiroyuki[nZk]:mizuki in the Aldnoah Zero opening/ending/insert songs, so I tried looking for other songs that she sang.

However, I can't seem to find anything on her. The main issue is a one word name is very ambiguous, and so googling "Mizuki" or "Mizuki singer" brings up a lot of results for Nana Mizuki and other singers with Mizuki in their names.

If I google "Mizuki aldnoah zero", which disambiguates my query a bit, then the problem is that I just get all the songs she produced for Aldnoah Zero, which I am already well aware of.

So does the Mizuki in question go by the name "Mizuki", in which case, any tips for differentiating her from other singers with "Mizuki" in their names?

Or does she go by a full name that got omitted in SawanoHiroyuki[nZk]:mizuki or a completely different one?

Or is she just only producing music under the name SawanoHiroyuki[nZk]:mizuki? (I ask this because Aimer still has songs under her own name even though she collaborated with Hiroyuki Sawano as SawanoHiroyuki[nZk]:Aimer)

Answer (score 9):

The mizuki in question is [this mizuki](http://vgmdb.net/artist/15897). Her personal blogs (in Japanese) are [５６番線 on ameblo](http://ameblo.jp/itsuemidori/) and [note.mu/mizuaoi](https://note.mu/mizuaoi). Her Twitter handle is [@mizukizuiaoi](https://twitter.com/mizukizuiaoi).

> Or is she just only producing music under the name SawanoHiroyuki[nZk]:mizuki?

She seems to be the vocalist for [the band "Itsue"](http://itsue.jp/about/), where she is also known by the single name "mizuki" (but it's written in Japanese as 瑞葵 there). Their [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/itsueband/videos) has a few of their songs, which have vocals by her. Their [discography page](http://itsue.jp/discography/) has links to purchase more of their music, if you're interested.

> Or does she go by a full name that got omitted in SawanoHiroyuki[nZk]:mizuki or a completely different one?

She doesn't seem to go by a full (two-part) name in any of her public appearances. This isn't terribly surprising; I get the impression that pseudonym among Japanese music artists is fairly common.

> So does the Mizuki in question go by the name "Mizuki", in which case, any tips for differentiating her from other singers with "Mizuki" in their names?

Your best bets are probably to search for things like "nzk mizuki" (for her stuff co-produced with Sawano, which at present is just the Aldnoah.Zero stuff) or "itsue mizuki" (for her band work; in Japanese, "イツエ 瑞葵").